# ~に~があります vs ~は~です in this sentence

Tags: grammar, nuances

The following sentence was found in a book:

日本社会の「きまり」にかかわる例の一つに、 会社への就職活動がある。

I'm wondering, assuming the translation is "An example of one of these "rules" related to Japanese society is job-hunting", wouldn't it make more sense to word the sentence like:

日本社会の「きまり」にかかわる例の一つは、 会社への就職活動です/である。

Or something like

日本社会の「きまり」にかかわる例の中に、 会社への就職活動がある。

What are the nuances of writing the sentence as shown in the book, with ~に~がある?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13249/1478

Comment: So the に just functions as として. That makes sense, although I'm not sure why they wouldn't just use として instead. But a lot of Japanese grammar has never made sense to me, so I'll just accept it. Thanks

Comment: Although this isn't recognized by traditional grammar, I think it's the adverbial form に `n-i` "as" of the copula `n-`.  Compare the adnominal form の `n-o`, as in 医者の娘 `doctor-COP daughter` "my daughter who is a doctor", versus the genitive の `no`, as in 医者の娘 `doctor-GEN daughter` "the doctor's daughter".

Comment: I closed as a duplicate because you seem satisfied with the answers I linked to, but I think there's room to reopen it if you (or others) think it should remain open.